# Video for HTML5 -- ffmpeg commands

Tags: video, ffmpeg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What bunch of ffmpeg scripts do I need to run “Video for everybody”?](https://superuser.com/questions/424015/what-bunch-of-ffmpeg-scripts-do-i-need-to-run-video-for-everybody)

I'd like to allow my users to upload their videos (no clue what format they'll be) and convert them into the following formats:

- MP4
- Ogg
- Webm

I think it's those 3 formats I need in order to support HTML5, at least per http://mediaelementjs.com/. I've tried various commands that I found on the web. Some of them worked, some of them used old syntax, some of them worked only on my computer and not others, some of them gave conflicting information, etc.

Are there any FFMPEG experts here that can provide the "proper" commands? I'm not particularly trying to achieve anything special. I just want to be able to convert the video into something playable on the web. Highest quality, smallest filesize, etc. are the basic goals.

Something that works without a lot of special configurations would be ideal, too. I ran into a lot of "missing presets" problems.

Comment: I think I covered everything in the question linked to. If you think this is not a duplicate, just let me know and I'll reopen and try to answer again.

Comment: Oh, and make sure you run the latest FFmpeg version, at least over v11. Presets have been removed from FFmpeg for quite some time now

Comment: @slhck - I will test your solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Should there be more options we should consider? One example I saw had `scale="trunc(oh*a*2)/2:480"`. Seems pretty important?

Comment: This is just a filter that scales the video down to 480 pixels height, keeping the original aspect ratio. Whether this is important or not depends on your application, but I wouldn't scale any video if I didn't have to.