# ffmpeg mp4 not playing on iPhone or on Safari/OSX 10.11.3

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, safari, mp4, ios

**UPDATE: After downloading the latest Windows build (3.2.2), encoding a video using baseline 3.0, and uploading that video to our test environment, the latest video DOES play on OSX/Safari as well as iOS/Safari on iPhone 6.
I think the only solution is going to be to pester our corporate overlords to upgrade ffmpeg on the servers.
Thanks for all your help, and sorry if I've wasted anyone's time on this.**

---

Having problems getting videos to play on iPhones (have only tried iPhone 6 so far) and on Safari on a MacBook. These videos play fine on Android devices and on IE11/Chrome on Windows, also on Chrome/OSX.

FWIW, this is the video player:

```
<video style="width:480px; height:320px" controls preload >
    <source src="my_source_variable" type="video/mp4" >
</video>
```

Here is my current encoding:

```
ffmpeg -y -i #arguments.input# -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -profile:v baseline -level 
3.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -ac 2 -strict experimental -b:a 128k -s 480x274 
#arguments.output#
```

And here is a sample ffmpeg output:

```
Success::318FA277-FEBB-DBB4-D76D9AFE89C2AD27--ffmpeg version 0.10.15 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 30 2014 15:49:19 with gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libcelt --enable-libdc1394 --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
  libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
  libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, asf, from 'raw/20170203_318FA277-FEBB-DBB4-D76D9AFE89C2AD27.wmv':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKVersion   : 10.00.00.3705
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    IsVBR           : 1
    VBR Peak        : 387
    Buffer Average  : 108
  Duration: 00:01:06.59, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 457 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: wmv2 (WMV2 / 0x32564D57), yuv420p, 480x252, 307 kb/s, 14.99 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
[buffer @ 0x17c3ec0] w:480 h:252 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000000 sar:0/1 sws_param:
[scale @ 0x17f5680] w:480 h:252 fmt:yuv420p -> w:480 h:274 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
Incompatible sample format 's16' for codec 'aac', auto-selecting format 'flt'
[libx264 @ 0x17cd6e0] using cpu capabilities: none!
[libx264 @ 0x17cd6e0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x17cd6e0] 264 - core 120 r2151 a3f4407 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2011 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=14 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'converted/20170203_318FA277-FEBB-DBB4-D76D9AFE89C2AD27.mp4':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKVersion   : 10.00.00.3705
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    IsVBR           : 1
    VBR Peak        : 387
    Buffer Average  : 108
    encoder         : Lavf53.32.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (![0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 480x274, q=-1--1, 15k tbn, 14.99 tbc
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (@[0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, flt, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (wmv2 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (wmav2 -> aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   75 fps=  0 q=27.0 size=     105kB time=00:00:01.09 bitrate= 791.6kbits/s dup=47 drop=0    
frame=  112 fps= 85 q=27.0 size=     182kB time=00:00:04.53 bitrate= 328.3kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  144 fps= 79 q=27.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:06.67 bitrate= 313.7kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  158 fps= 68 q=27.0 size=     348kB time=00:00:07.40 bitrate= 384.7kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  175 fps= 62 q=27.0 size=     403kB time=00:00:08.10 bitrate= 407.6kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  197 fps= 59 q=27.0 size=     492kB time=00:00:09.77 bitrate= 412.3kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  217 fps= 56 q=27.0 size=     578kB time=00:00:10.98 bitrate= 431.3kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  233 fps= 53 q=27.0 size=     660kB time=00:00:12.19 bitrate= 443.7kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  249 fps= 51 q=27.0 size=     735kB time=00:00:13.25 bitrate= 454.3kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  264 fps= 49 q=27.0 size=     810kB time=00:00:14.37 bitrate= 461.4kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  286 fps= 48 q=27.0 size=     906kB time=00:00:15.76 bitrate= 470.5kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  300 fps= 47 q=27.0 size=     964kB time=00:00:16.46 bitrate= 479.5kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  314 fps= 45 q=27.0 size=    1025kB time=00:00:17.34 bitrate= 484.1kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  326 fps= 44 q=27.0 size=    1094kB time=00:00:18.36 bitrate= 488.1kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  339 fps= 42 q=27.0 size=    1165kB time=00:00:19.11 bitrate= 499.6kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  350 fps= 41 q=27.0 size=    1241kB time=00:00:19.99 bitrate= 508.5kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  364 fps= 40 q=27.0 size=    1316kB time=00:00:20.78 bitrate= 518.7kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  378 fps= 40 q=27.0 size=    1374kB time=00:00:21.61 bitrate= 520.8kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  392 fps= 39 q=27.0 size=    1447kB time=00:00:22.54 bitrate= 525.8kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  408 fps= 38 q=27.0 size=    1537kB time=00:00:23.66 bitrate= 532.2kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  423 fps= 38 q=27.0 size=    1612kB time=00:00:24.77 bitrate= 533.0kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  439 fps= 38 q=27.0 size=    1687kB time=00:00:25.89 bitrate= 533.8kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  452 fps= 37 q=27.0 size=    1747kB time=00:00:26.77 bitrate= 534.5kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  462 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    1820kB time=00:00:27.56 bitrate= 540.9kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  476 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    1894kB time=00:00:28.53 bitrate= 543.8kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  488 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    1946kB time=00:00:29.28 bitrate= 544.6kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  503 fps= 35 q=27.0 size=    2018kB time=00:00:30.16 bitrate= 548.0kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  517 fps= 35 q=27.0 size=    2089kB time=00:00:31.23 bitrate= 548.1kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  539 fps= 35 q=27.0 size=    2172kB time=00:00:32.48 bitrate= 547.8kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  556 fps= 35 q=27.0 size=    2247kB time=00:00:33.69 bitrate= 546.2kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  577 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    2333kB time=00:00:35.22 bitrate= 542.6kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  601 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    2429kB time=00:00:36.57 bitrate= 544.1kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  627 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    2524kB time=00:00:38.61 bitrate= 535.4kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  653 fps= 37 q=27.0 size=    2591kB time=00:00:40.00 bitrate= 530.5kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  679 fps= 37 q=27.0 size=    2664kB time=00:00:41.86 bitrate= 521.4kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  695 fps= 37 q=27.0 size=    2721kB time=00:00:42.84 bitrate= 520.3kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  710 fps= 37 q=27.0 size=    2798kB time=00:00:44.09 bitrate= 519.9kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  726 fps= 37 q=27.0 size=    2854kB time=00:00:44.88 bitrate= 520.9kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  741 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    2924kB time=00:00:45.99 bitrate= 520.8kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  766 fps= 37 q=27.0 size=    3035kB time=00:00:47.71 bitrate= 521.1kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  789 fps= 37 q=24.0 size=    3123kB time=00:00:49.29 bitrate= 518.9kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  804 fps= 37 q=27.0 size=    3198kB time=00:00:50.22 bitrate= 521.6kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  816 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    3288kB time=00:00:51.15 bitrate= 526.6kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  828 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    3359kB time=00:00:51.89 bitrate= 530.1kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  841 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    3439kB time=00:00:52.82 bitrate= 533.4kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  854 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    3502kB time=00:00:53.75 bitrate= 533.8kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  868 fps= 35 q=27.0 size=    3582kB time=00:00:54.63 bitrate= 537.1kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  885 fps= 35 q=27.0 size=    3653kB time=00:00:55.70 bitrate= 537.2kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  910 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    3743kB time=00:00:57.09 bitrate= 537.0kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  932 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    3832kB time=00:00:58.86 bitrate= 533.3kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  946 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    3906kB time=00:00:59.69 bitrate= 535.9kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  960 fps= 35 q=27.0 size=    3990kB time=00:01:00.81 bitrate= 537.6kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  982 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    4091kB time=00:01:02.15 bitrate= 539.1kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  997 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    4193kB time=00:01:03.59 bitrate= 540.1kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
frame=  997 fps= 34 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4448kB time=00:01:06.53 bitrate= 547.7kbits/s dup=69 drop=0    
video:3375kB audio:1046kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.613058%
[libx264 @ 0x17cd6e0] frame I:15    Avg QP:16.92  size: 20595
[libx264 @ 0x17cd6e0] frame P:982   Avg QP:23.30  size:  3205
[libx264 @ 0x17cd6e0] mb I  I16..4: 23.9%  0.0% 76.1%
[libx264 @ 0x17cd6e0] mb P  I16..4:  1.6%  0.0%  2.1%  P16..4: 32.8% 15.4%  5.9%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:42.1%
[libx264 @ 0x17cd6e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 52.5% 74.5% 50.1% inter: 22.1% 29.4% 5.4%
[libx264 @ 0x17cd6e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 58% 24% 10%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x17cd6e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 45% 14% 14%  3%  4%  6%  4%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x17cd6e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 37% 16% 41%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x17cd6e0] ref P L0: 90.0%  6.5%  3.5%
[libx264 @ 0x17cd6e0] kb/s:415.53
-
```

As I'm a total novice at this, I'm just been relying on my Google friend for suggestions. The above encoding was a suggestion from

[What ffmpeg command line produces video more compatible across all devices?](https://superuser.com/questions/859010/what-ffmpeg-command-line-produces-video-more-compatible-across-all-devices)

and is used as suggested, minus the faststart flag. EDIT: I removed faststart because encoding failed with both "faststart" and "+faststart". Sample relevant output:

```
[mp4 muxer @ 0x75d200] [Eval @ 0x7ffc607b1ae0] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'faststart'
[mp4 muxer @ 0x75d200] Unable to parse option value "faststart"
[mp4 muxer @ 0x75d200] Error setting option movflags to value +faststart.
```

I'll continue to search and experiment while waiting for the answers to come streaming in ;-) but the only clue I have right now is the "Incompatible sample format" warning, which, as it's only a warning, probably isn't that important.

When I inspect the network traffic in Web Inspector, I see that the status, size, and transferred fields are blank. There are no console errors.

Also, when I try directly accessing the file in Safari on a MacBook, it won't load, but it will in Chrome.

P.S. as noted below, our ffmpeg is ancient; I have no control over that.

EDIT: per suggestion, added -an flag; still doesn't play on iPhone; moving on to -vn flag next;

```
ffmpeg -y -i #arguments.input# -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -profile:v baseline -level 
3.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -ac 2 -strict experimental -b:a 128k -an -s 480x274 
#arguments.output#
```

Output:

```
Success::CB4156A5-CC1F-15A0-34764A179FD90A04--ffmpeg version 0.10.15 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 30 2014 15:49:19 with gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libcelt --enable-libdc1394 --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
  libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
  libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, asf, from 'raw/20170206_CB4156A5-CC1F-15A0-34764A179FD90A04.wmv':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKVersion   : 10.00.00.3705
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    IsVBR           : 1
    VBR Peak        : 366
    Buffer Average  : 125
  Duration: 00:01:24.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 459 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: wmv2 (WMV2 / 0x32564D57), yuv420p, 480x252, 307 kb/s, 14.99 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
[buffer @ 0x2258d00] w:480 h:252 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000000 sar:0/1 sws_param:
[scale @ 0x2266200] w:480 h:252 fmt:yuv420p -> w:480 h:274 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
[libx264 @ 0x2262920] using cpu capabilities: none!
[libx264 @ 0x2262920] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x2262920] 264 - core 120 r2151 a3f4407 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2011 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=14 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'converted/20170206_CB4156A5-CC1F-15A0-34764A179FD90A04.mp4':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKVersion   : 10.00.00.3705
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    IsVBR           : 1
    VBR Peak        : 366
    Buffer Average  : 125
    encoder         : Lavf53.32.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (![0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 480x274, q=-1--1, 15k tbn, 14.99 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (wmv2 -> libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   73 fps= 60 q=27.0 size=      97kB time=00:00:01.93 bitrate= 412.3kbits/s dup=43 drop=0    
frame=  120 fps= 69 q=27.0 size=     125kB time=00:00:05.07 bitrate= 202.6kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  150 fps= 66 q=27.0 size=     216kB time=00:00:07.07 bitrate= 249.6kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  186 fps= 66 q=27.0 size=     285kB time=00:00:09.47 bitrate= 246.5kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  197 fps= 59 q=27.0 size=     352kB time=00:00:10.21 bitrate= 282.0kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  211 fps= 55 q=27.0 size=     426kB time=00:00:11.14 bitrate= 312.9kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  226 fps= 52 q=27.0 size=     495kB time=00:00:12.14 bitrate= 334.2kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  239 fps= 49 q=27.0 size=     544kB time=00:00:13.01 bitrate= 342.7kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  253 fps= 47 q=27.0 size=     598kB time=00:00:13.94 bitrate= 351.2kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  267 fps= 45 q=27.0 size=     663kB time=00:00:14.88 bitrate= 364.9kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  281 fps= 44 q=27.0 size=     709kB time=00:00:15.81 bitrate= 367.1kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  295 fps= 42 q=27.0 size=     764kB time=00:00:16.75 bitrate= 373.7kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  309 fps= 41 q=27.0 size=     820kB time=00:00:17.68 bitrate= 379.6kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  327 fps= 41 q=27.0 size=     901kB time=00:00:18.88 bitrate= 391.0kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  357 fps= 42 q=27.0 size=     966kB time=00:00:20.88 bitrate= 378.8kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  375 fps= 41 q=27.0 size=    1036kB time=00:00:22.08 bitrate= 384.3kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  389 fps= 41 q=27.0 size=    1079kB time=00:00:23.02 bitrate= 383.9kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  405 fps= 40 q=27.0 size=    1140kB time=00:00:24.09 bitrate= 387.5kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  420 fps= 40 q=27.0 size=    1198kB time=00:00:25.09 bitrate= 391.0kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  433 fps= 39 q=27.0 size=    1246kB time=00:00:25.95 bitrate= 393.1kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  445 fps= 38 q=27.0 size=    1291kB time=00:00:26.76 bitrate= 395.3kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  458 fps= 38 q=27.0 size=    1350kB time=00:00:27.62 bitrate= 400.4kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  470 fps= 37 q=27.0 size=    1394kB time=00:00:28.42 bitrate= 401.7kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  484 fps= 37 q=27.0 size=    1457kB time=00:00:29.36 bitrate= 406.4kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  497 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    1502kB time=00:00:30.23 bitrate= 406.9kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  509 fps= 36 q=27.0 size=    1551kB time=00:00:31.03 bitrate= 409.5kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  522 fps= 35 q=27.0 size=    1608kB time=00:00:31.89 bitrate= 413.1kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  534 fps= 35 q=27.0 size=    1656kB time=00:00:32.69 bitrate= 414.8kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  547 fps= 35 q=27.0 size=    1713kB time=00:00:33.56 bitrate= 418.2kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  561 fps= 34 q=27.0 size=    1768kB time=00:00:34.50 bitrate= 419.8kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  573 fps= 34 q=27.0 size=    1815kB time=00:00:35.30 bitrate= 421.1kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  587 fps= 34 q=27.0 size=    1865kB time=00:00:36.23 bitrate= 421.6kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  601 fps= 34 q=27.0 size=    1930kB time=00:00:37.17 bitrate= 425.4kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  615 fps= 33 q=27.0 size=    1987kB time=00:00:38.10 bitrate= 427.1kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  629 fps= 33 q=27.0 size=    2042kB time=00:00:39.03 bitrate= 428.5kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  645 fps= 33 q=27.0 size=    2107kB time=00:00:40.10 bitrate= 430.3kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  659 fps= 33 q=27.0 size=    2162kB time=00:00:41.04 bitrate= 431.6kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  672 fps= 33 q=27.0 size=    2210kB time=00:00:41.90 bitrate= 432.1kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  686 fps= 33 q=27.0 size=    2259kB time=00:00:42.84 bitrate= 432.0kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  698 fps= 32 q=27.0 size=    2303kB time=00:00:43.64 bitrate= 432.2kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  712 fps= 32 q=27.0 size=    2361kB time=00:00:44.57 bitrate= 433.9kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  726 fps= 32 q=27.0 size=    2411kB time=00:00:45.51 bitrate= 433.9kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  740 fps= 32 q=27.0 size=    2473kB time=00:00:46.44 bitrate= 436.2kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  753 fps= 32 q=27.0 size=    2541kB time=00:00:47.31 bitrate= 440.0kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  766 fps= 32 q=27.0 size=    2602kB time=00:00:48.18 bitrate= 442.5kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  779 fps= 32 q=27.0 size=    2671kB time=00:00:49.04 bitrate= 446.1kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  796 fps= 32 q=27.0 size=    2734kB time=00:00:50.18 bitrate= 446.4kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  808 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    2775kB time=00:00:50.98 bitrate= 445.9kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  824 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    2839kB time=00:00:52.05 bitrate= 446.8kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  837 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    2888kB time=00:00:52.91 bitrate= 447.1kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  849 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    2932kB time=00:00:53.72 bitrate= 447.2kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  863 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    2983kB time=00:00:54.65 bitrate= 447.1kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  878 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    3043kB time=00:00:55.65 bitrate= 447.8kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  891 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    3097kB time=00:00:56.52 bitrate= 448.8kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  905 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    3142kB time=00:00:57.45 bitrate= 447.9kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  919 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    3204kB time=00:00:58.39 bitrate= 449.4kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  949 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    3272kB time=00:01:00.39 bitrate= 443.8kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  984 fps= 32 q=27.0 size=    3325kB time=00:01:02.72 bitrate= 434.2kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame=  998 fps= 32 q=27.0 size=    3384kB time=00:01:03.66 bitrate= 435.4kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame= 1011 fps= 32 q=27.0 size=    3429kB time=00:01:04.53 bitrate= 435.3kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame= 1024 fps= 32 q=27.0 size=    3473kB time=00:01:05.39 bitrate= 435.1kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame= 1038 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    3517kB time=00:01:06.33 bitrate= 434.4kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame= 1052 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    3578kB time=00:01:07.26 bitrate= 435.8kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame= 1070 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    3646kB time=00:01:08.46 bitrate= 436.3kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame= 1085 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    3702kB time=00:01:09.46 bitrate= 436.6kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame= 1102 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    3751kB time=00:01:10.60 bitrate= 435.2kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame= 1119 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    3808kB time=00:01:11.73 bitrate= 434.8kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame= 1133 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    3853kB time=00:01:12.67 bitrate= 434.3kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame= 1146 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    3889kB time=00:01:13.54 bitrate= 433.3kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame= 1160 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    3960kB time=00:01:14.47 bitrate= 435.6kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame= 1173 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    4009kB time=00:01:15.34 bitrate= 435.9kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame= 1186 fps= 31 q=24.0 size=    4055kB time=00:01:16.20 bitrate= 435.9kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame= 1200 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    4121kB time=00:01:17.14 bitrate= 437.6kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame= 1214 fps= 31 q=27.0 size=    4175kB time=00:01:18.07 bitrate= 438.0kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame= 1251 fps= 32 q=27.0 size=    4254kB time=00:01:20.54 bitrate= 432.7kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
frame= 1255 fps= 31 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4336kB time=00:01:23.75 bitrate= 424.1kbits/s dup=66 drop=0    
video:4330kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.134247%
[libx264 @ 0x2262920] frame I:24    Avg QP:18.57  size: 19218
[libx264 @ 0x2262920] frame P:1231  Avg QP:23.50  size:  3227
[libx264 @ 0x2262920] mb I  I16..4: 17.6%  0.0% 82.4%
[libx264 @ 0x2262920] mb P  I16..4:  1.3%  0.0%  2.4%  P16..4: 38.4% 18.0%  6.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:33.4%
[libx264 @ 0x2262920] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 58.9% 72.5% 44.8% inter: 22.4% 29.9% 4.7%
[libx264 @ 0x2262920] i16 v,h,dc,p: 62% 22% 10%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x2262920] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 46% 17% 12%  4%  4%  4%  4%  4%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x2262920] i8c dc,h,v,p: 37% 17% 40%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x2262920] ref P L0: 87.5%  8.2%  4.3%
[libx264 @ 0x2262920] kb/s:423.52
-
```

Comment: Why no faststart? And your ffmpeg is ancient.

Comment: @Mulvya, I pulled out faststart because a) our lead tech doesn't want autoplay and b) I'm pulling out my hair trying to figure out the problem. As far as ffmpeg version, I'm aware but have no control.

Comment: Faststart is not autoplay. It simply places the index at the head of the MP4. Try skipping the audio `-an`

Comment: @mulvya, any chance the audio settings are the problem? I have to use -strict experimental because it's so old... wonder if the other settings are the problem. Also, see my update re: not playing in OSX/Safari

Comment: Nothing in the output looks obviously wrong, so some trial & error is required. So, try without the audio by adding `-an`. Then without the video `-vn`.

Comment: You're wasting your time (and ours) using such an old build. Why do you have no control over that? Also, your old build is showing `using cpu capabilities: none!` which means it will needlessly encode slowly. There's no need to compile to get a new version, just [download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/), extract, and execute.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, sorry to waste your time. I'm in a corporate environment where I have no control over server resources. Trust me, I'm not happy to struggle with this either. I'm also a new hire so have no clout.

Comment: Your ffmpeg is so old that faststart hadn't been added yet. Even though you can't upgrade ffmpeg, run your command with and without faststart on some other machine with a recent ffmpeg build to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Didn't you say you have a Mac? Can't you use Homebrew or something to install a proper build of ffmpeg on your Mac and convert the file there, at least for this experiment? If that makes all the difference, you can walk down the hall and slap your server admin with your success.

Comment: @Spiff, response from our tech lead re: upgrade: "We would need a write up on why the current version works and what specific version is required. However, from what we are told <our company> can only get software from a <company>-approved store, and what we have is the newest version available from the repo's that meet that requirement. So if what we have will not work then we simply cannot continue. To get the latest version it has to be compiled by source and they will not do this. Anything else has to be justified and <our manager> would have to escalate this through management."

Comment: So even your Mac is locked down and you can't install an open source software package on it yourself? Even one that shouldn't require admin privs?