# ffmpeg: yuv420p pixel format missing?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, arch-linux

Often when I search online for ffmpeg advice, I find the answer involves using the `-pix_fmt yuv420p` (or I think also `yuv720p`) argument. Example: [What ffmpeg command line produces video more compatible across all devices?](https://superuser.com/questions/859010/what-ffmpeg-command-line-produces-video-more-compatible-across-all-devices)

At least here on Arch Linux with ffmpeg 4.0.2-7, I have yet to ever successfully use that argument. Every time I do, I get `Unknown pixel format requested: yuv480p.` (or 720p).

What is going on? Why is my system missing what seems to be a crucial pixel format for cross-platform compatibility? According to Google, I'm the first person to ever have this problem.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Use yuv420p

There is no such thing as yuv480p or yuv720p because it is not tied to the video height. yuv420p is a [chroma subsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) scheme, and the `p` stands for *planar*, not *progressive*. In `ffmpeg` yuv420p is called a *pixel format*.

You can use the [format filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format), or the legacy `-pix_fmt` option, to set the pixel format. Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf format=yuv420p output.mp4
```

- See a generic list of supported pixel formats with `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`.
- See which pixel formats are supported by a specific encoder, such as `ffmpeg -h encoder=libx264`.

Comment: This is also the solution for videos downloaded via youtube-dl that error with "This file contains some media which isn’t compatible with QuickTime Player. Would you like to open the file anyway?" when trying to open on macOS