# How to combine WebM and Opus to generate MP4?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using following command but it is giving wrong output.

```
ffmpeg -i video.webm -i audio.opus -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental output.mp4
```

Output:

```
ffmpeg version 1.2.6-7:1.2.6-1~trusty1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 26 2014 18:52:58 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --arch=amd64 --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:1.2.6-1~trusty1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    53.  5.103 / 53.  5.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'video.webm':
  Duration: 00:00:04.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 243 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 18 fps, 18 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
Input #1, ogg, from 'audio.opus':
  Duration: 00:00:05.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16
[mp4 @ 0x647940] track 0: could not find tag, codec not currently supported in container
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 18 fps, 90k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (libopus -> aac)
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Next time when posting about an ffmpeg problem, please include the full, uncut command line output too, not just the command itself.

Comment: `Operation not permitted` hints at a filesystem permissions issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

WebM containers typically contain VP8 or VP9 video. The MP4 container format however does not support VP8 or VP9 video, at least [according to the registration authority](http://www.mp4ra.org/codecs.html).

In your command you are trying to copy the video bitstream, and obviously it will fail:

> codec not currently supported in container

You have two options:

1. Re-code the video to H.264 using `-c:v libx264`.
2. Choose another output container like Matroska (`.mkv`), but note that this will not be compatible for HTML5 video.

See also this [MDN reference on supported HTML video formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) and this Super User post on how to convert video for HTML5: [What bunch of ffmpeg scripts do I need to get HTML5-compatible "Video for everybody"?](https://superuser.com/questions/424015/what-bunch-of-ffmpeg-scripts-do-i-need-to-get-html5-compatible-video-for-everyb)

Comment: can you help me with the command to convert to any HTML supported video format?

Comment: See here: http://superuser.com/questions/424015/what-bunch-of-ffmpeg-scripts-do-i-need-to-get-html5-compatible-video-for-everyb

Comment: Thanks I understood what you said. Command I am using now is: `ffmpeg -i video.webm -i audio.opus -c:v copy -c:a libvorbis -strict experimental output.webm`

Comment: Yes, although you should even be able to do `-c:a copy` since WebM supports Opus audio. `-strict experimental` is only needed when using `-c:a aac`.

Answer (score 3):

```
ffmpeg -i video.webm -i audio.opus -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental output.mp4
```

it should look something like this.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.opus -i vid.webm  -c:v copy -c:a opus -strict experimental output6.webm
```

replace aac with opus and the two files around with opus being in front(i think), it should work.

Answer (score 0):

A simple command with copy option with the conversion from webm to mp4 doesn't work because of difference in a codec which we don't touch during conversion. It is like simply changing the extension of the input file.
To make sure the output is played in H.264 players/televisions use

```
ffmpeg -y -i "input_video.webm" -i "input_audio.webm" "output_file.mp4"  -c:v libx264 -c:a aac
```

Note that the execution will be very slow and add `-preset veryfast` depending on your quality needs.
Ref: https://addpipe.com/blog/converting-webm-to-mp4-with-ffmpeg/